# java bigquery storage write api

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using the java bigquery storage api as documented here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api.
Keeping the write stream long lived and refreshing it when one of the non-retry-able errors happened as per this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#error_handling

I am sticking with default stream. I have two tables and different parts of code responsible for writing to each table, maintaining its own stream writer.

If data is flowing, everything is fine. No errors. However I want to test refreshing the stream writers work too so I wait for default stream timeout (10mins) which closes the stream and try writing again. I can create the stream fine, no error there, but for one of the table I keep getting cancelled error wrapped in a Pre condition failed making my code refresh again and again.

Original error because stream closed due to inactivity

```
! io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Stream is closed due to com.google.api.gax.rpc.AbortedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Closing the stream because it has been inactive for 600 seconds. Entity: projects/<id>/datasets/<id>/tables/<id>/_default
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.StreamWriterV2.appendInternal(StreamWriterV2.java:263)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.StreamWriterV2.append(StreamWriterV2.java:234)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.JsonStreamWriter.append(JsonStreamWriter.java:114)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.JsonStreamWriter.append(JsonStreamWriter.java:89)
```

Further repeating errors on new stream(s)

```
! io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Stream is closed due to com.google.api.gax.rpc.CancelledException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.StreamWriterV2.appendInternal(StreamWriterV2.java:263)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.StreamWriterV2.append(StreamWriterV2.java:234)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.JsonStreamWriter.append(JsonStreamWriter.java:114)
! at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.JsonStreamWriter.append(JsonStreamWriter.java:89)
```

I am not sure why its being cancelled without error. Any pointers on how I can debug this or recommendation on how to maintain and refresh a long-lived streaming writer?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? Can you provide more details on how to reproduce the error you encountered? Can you share the code and sample input tables to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the Java client library version should solve this problem since reconnect support was added for the JsonStreamwriter. Instead of throwing this error, it should handle retries.

Comment: Yeah the new version v1 works without the error. Thank you

Comment: Same issue is happening with google bigquery storage for node.js